# Awkward reflection on mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have made an object using 2 different mesh. On the top of the sphere, I'm getting a shape which reflects looking like some sort of sun with its rays indicated within the red ellipse.

And also I've joined the 2 mesh to make it one object, but the edges are too harsh, what's the best way to make it blend in smoother?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello sir. It seems like a simple problem with mesh topology. Consider uploading your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so others can take a look :).

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6816" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6816/)

here is the file, thanks for taking a look into it. I'd like to know what I've done incorrect, in order to understand my mistake and take better consideration regarding the mesh.

Thank you.

Comment: I checked the file and found several issues. I'll post an answer adressing all of them, including a repaired blendfile, but it will take a minute :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me adress the issues :).
I also attached a repaired blendfile at the end.

01) The 'sun like' pattern appears when *Subdivision Modifier* is applied on a triangle fan. Just play a bit with the size of the triangles, or use *Face->Grid fill* to fill the cap with quads.

02) The edges are harsh, because they are not connected.
You have two meshes *joined* into one object, but that's not enough. They're just going through each other.
You need to connect the vertices of those two meshes, so they create one continuous mesh.

---

Other tips for your workflow:
1) There's no need to use *Edit cage option* in the *Subdivision modifier*.
In this case it just deforms the mesh without any benefit.
You also don't need 4 levels of subdivision. 2 levels are enough.

*Example of my settings*
[image]

2)  Use milimeters, and *absolute grid snapping*. It will make your modelling considerably easier, especially when modelling real world objects.

[image] [image]

3) When using *mirror modifier*, make sure your mesh is cut in half. Otherwise the *mirror modifier* will create double-faces which are a pain in the ass to deal with :).
Your original mesh has a few of these.

Here is your repaired Blendfile. Check the differences, and find out which way works best for you.
The meshes are not connected, you'll need to do it yourself.
[image]

If you'll need any clarification, let me know.
You're doing great, happy Blendering :).

Comment: Thanks so much for your information, this is extremely important indications since I am currently learning Blender.

Kind regards.

Comment: @graphomet Happy to help. Welcome aboard.